# Why does google chrome do a full page reload on postback?

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-chrome

I am creating one of my first Asp.Net tools and I ran in to a small bump.

Currently I am doing a postback on a buttonclick which does some server-side calculations. The server-side code then uses those calculations to alter the contents of a div. In IE and Firefox when a postback happens, the div updates as expected.

However, in chrome all postbacks do a complete refresh of the entire page. What is causing this and is there a way around this behavior?

Update:
ClientSide I have the following..

```
    <asp:Button ID="Button2" Style="float: right" runat="server" 
OnClick="S_ButtonClick" Text="Calculate" />
```

Which calls a method summarized as so.

```
protected void S_ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        //Code parsing values from textboxes ect.

        //Do Some Calculations

        //Output Results
        outputDiv.InnerHtml = "<h2>Foo</h2><br/>";
        outputDiv.InnerHtml += "Bar: " + calcValue;

    }
```

It is possible that when this postback(if I understand this correctly) happens, that it is still fully reloading in firefox and ie, but it doesn't show it. This effectively masks the postback. However, when I test in chrome, any postback completely blanks the page before reloading the state. Hopefully this clears up exactly what I am asking. Also, my C#/.Net usage might be slightly flawed and I am willing to take comments on such.

Comment: AFAIK, that is the expected behaviour on a postback unless you are using AJAX. Are you using any AJAX library?

Comment: You need to provide more information about what you're doing, exactly.  Typically, a postback does cause a full page refresh, so it sounds like you're talking about ASP.NET AJAX, not a traditional postback.

Comment: I think you're talking about callbacks, not postbacks. if you're using update panels and if you're running any javascript on the page, you might want to make sure it's working in Chrome. Sometimes broken client-side validators will cause issues in update panels resulting in postback instead of a callback.

Comment: Ah, the joys of languages that abstract what actually gets sent to the browser...

Comment: Are you sure in IE and firefox the page isn't full refreshing???

Comment: @maleki because ie/firefox have a different render on the page you think that they not postback the full page, but they did. You have mix up the post back with the Ajax.

Comment: I agree with Carlos.  I would image IE does the same thing, but the page refresh is just not as noticable.

Comment: @everyone Doing a little testing, I quickly realized that all were behaving the same. However IE and firefox seem to handle postback in a more aesthetic manner than chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it, ASP.NET AJAX partial postbacks are only support on browsers ASP.NET can detect. The last I heard (a while ago) that was ie, firefox and Safari, not Chrome. In that case it resorts to full postbacks.

To implement page updates I'd really recommend you switch to jQuery or another widely supported AJAX toolkit. (jQuery is support by Microsoft if that's an issue) There's a little bit more plumbing involved, but not much.

Comment: So would this allow me to perform the necessary state update and server-side code execution when something like a checkbox is clicked, all without performing a postback?

Comment: Correct.  From javascript you can call a page on the server using the "$.ajax" function. The page will execute on the server and you can take the response (html or otherwise) and append it to a div or whatever on your page. http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials

Comment: I posted my solution as an answer but I will accept yours because it seems more appropriate.